# How to extract row in vertical condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Now I have dataframe below

```
A B C
1 a 1
1 b 0
1 c 0
1 d 1
2 e 1
2 f 1
2 g 0
3 h 1
3 i 0
3 j 1
3 k 1
```

I would like to extract in condition with df.C

in each number of df.A, for example number 1

df.query("A==1")=

```
A B C
1 a 1
1 b 0
1 c 1
1 d 1
```

In df.C, the number 1 is sandwiched between one or more zeros.

df.query("A==1").C=

```
1
0
1
1
```

so this frame is extracted.

But the frame df.query("A==2") does not match above condition.

In summary ,I would like to dataframe below

```
A B C
1 a 1
1 b 0
1 c 0
1 d 1
3 h 1
3 i 0
3 j 1
3 k 1
```

Comment: are you after `df.query("A != 2")`?

Comment: So you want to group by A then for each value of A, C must start and end with 1 and contain at least one 0?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [filtration](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration) - check first and last values in `C` in each `group` is not `0`:

```
print (df)
    A  B  C
0   1  a  1
1   1  b  0
2   1  c  0
3   1  d  1
4   2  e  1
5   2  f  1
6   2  g  0
7   3  h  1
8   3  i  1
9   3  j  0
10  3  k  1
11  4  j  0
12  4  k  0
13  4  k  1

df = df.groupby('A').filter(lambda x: not (x.C.iat[0] == 0 or x.C.iat[-1] == 0))
print (df)
    A  B  C
0   1  a  1
1   1  b  0
2   1  c  0
3   1  d  1
7   3  h  1
8   3  i  1
9   3  j  0
10  3  k  1
```

But if in some group is possible not `0` you have to check it too:

```
df = df.groupby('A')
       .filter(lambda x: not (x.C.iat[0] == 0 or x.C.iat[-1] == 0) and (x.C == 0).any())
```

Comment: Your solution only works on the condition that there is only one `1` before the `0`s or am I wrong? What if `C` is `1,1,0,1`?

Comment: Solution was changed, please check it.

Comment: Works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

You already accepted the first answer but I'll still post this long and messier one.

You can use different groupbys to get necessary numbers for boolean indexing.

```
dg = df.groupby('A')

Cf = dg.C.first()
Cl = dg.C.last()
Cs = dg.C.sum()
Cc = dg.C.count()

dd = pd.DataFrame([Cf,Cl,Cs,Cc]).T.reset_index()
dd.columns = ['A','CFirst','CLast','CSum','CCount']

de = pd.merge(df,dd,on='A',how='left')

res = de[(de.CCount > de.CSum)&(de.CFirst+de.CLast == 2)]
res = res.drop(["CFirst","CLast","CSum","CCount"],axis=1)
```